# Query to identify if a time period is between times that pass through midnight?

Tags: date, datetime, ms-access

I'm in the process of designing a database to identify if work can be performed during a time period.
I also have to take into account the day of the week but I've done this by testing against the start days allowed which are stored in a table.

So for example, a department allows work between 18:00 - 08:00.

I have a start time in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn called start_date
and a end time in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn called end_date

The solution I currently use is to think the wrong way round so I'm testing if the start time is between 08:00 and 18:00 if not that's OK.
I then perform the same on the end date, plus I calculate if the HOURDIFF is greater than the allowed window i.e 14hours.

Is there a better way to test if times are between a range that cross midnight?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if you have the dates, then if the end_date is on a different date than start_date, then the shift is necessarily crossing midnight.

If you don't have the dates and only have two times, the shift would cross midnight if the end_date's time is less than the start_date's time.